# How to build this Laravel Eloquent Query

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I want to build a nested array from a simple table with Laravel Eloquent, but i couldn't.

So basically below is a snap shot of my table

[image]

and this is the array I want to build

[image]

Comment: What is the result (error message)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some methods from [**collection**](https://laravel.com/docs/collections) :

```
$result = $data->groupBy(['market_id', 'base_currency', 'currency_id'])
    ->map(function ($item) {
        return $item->map(function ($item) {
            return $item->map(function ($item) {
                return $item->map(function ($item) {
                    return $item['currency_id'];
                });
            })->flatten();
        })->sortKeys();
    });

dd($result->toArray());
```

```
array:1 [
  1 => array:2 [
    1 => array:2 [
      0 => 2
      1 => 3
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
      0 => 1
      1 => 2
    ]
  ]
]
```

---

### Explanation

#### `groupBy`

The `groupBy` method groups the collection's items by a given key. Multiple grouping criteria may be passed as an array. Each array element will be applied to the corresponding level within a multi-dimensional array:

```
$data->groupBy(['market_id', 'base_currency', 'currency_id']);
```

#### `map`

The `map` method iterates through the collection and passes each value to the given callback.

```
->map(function ($item) {
    return $item;
});
```

#### `flatten`

The `flatten` method flattens a multi-dimensional collection into a single dimension:

```
->flatten()
```

#### `sortKeys`

The `sortKeys` method sorts the collection by the keys of the underlying associative array:

```
->sortKeys()
```